# Scrapy: Is there a common mistake why Selector object is eating a lot of memory, when we check it in telnet?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, scrapy, telnet

[image]

here is the picture of prefs().
I solved my requests memory leak issue by using JOBDIR setting, but I can't find any issue related to selector object.
For confidentiality reasons I cannot paste whole spider file here but here is a small snippet:-

```
title = div.xpath('.//div/div/a/@title').extract_first()
pagelink = div.xpath('.//div/div/a/@href').extract_first()
isbn_10 = div.xpath(isbn_10_sel).extract_first()
isbn_13 = div.xpath(isbn_13_sel).extract_first()
```

it is all simple xpath selectors.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.